# s3fs not showing all the folders from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I am using s3fs to mount a bucket into an EC2 instance. The mount is successful but strangely not all folders present in my bucket are visible within the mount in the EC2 instance. The data within the S3 bucket was copied from another EC2 instance.

```
pkg-config --modversion fuse

2.9.2

s3fs --version

Amazon Simple Storage Service File System V1.91 (commit:9a42822) with OpenSSL
```

The command I have used to mount the bucket:

```
s3fs -o iam_role='MyS3Role' -o url='https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' -o allow_other -o nonempty -o use_path_request_style -o use_cache=/tmp -o umask=0002 mybucket /usr/test
```

Answer (score 4):

In version [1.92](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/releases/tag/v1.92), try adding the following option:

`-o compat_dir`

Comment: The comment on the commit says that not all applications create the `dir_$folder$` object. Seems like `compat_dir` option adds overhead, but will make things visible again in those situations.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with V1.91.
After checked out to V1.90, everything worked fine.

```
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/
```

```
git checkout cd466eb
```

```
./configure
```

```
make install
```

```
Amazon Simple Storage Service File System V1.90 (commit:cd466eb) with OpenSSL
```

Comment: Thanks @Nam Le. Will try out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After git checkout...

Do not forget to

```
./autogen.sh
```

then `./configure`

Answer (score 0):

1.93 addresses this issue.  1.92 introduced a regression with implicit directories that is not present in 1.91.  You should be able to work around this with `-o compat_dir` or by upgrading.  This symptom is tracked at:

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/pull/2212